# SYSLINUX 4.06 error on boot

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, syslinux

I'm a college student majoring in computer science and I thought it was finally time to switch to a "computer scientists" operation system. I decided to try ubuntu first because it seems like the easiest and most popular distro. I made a live usb using LiLi,Univerasl USB Installer, and Unetbootin. All give me the same error when booting from USB `SYSLINUX 4.06,(copyright info)`.

I have seen that many people have had this problem before and I haven't seen someone post a clear step by step solution yet. When posting your suggestions please remember that I am completely new to this OS and please excuse any of inexperience.

- OS: Windows 7
- Model: Acer Timelinex ect.
- USB: Sandisk 8gb

Other Info:
I have tries reformatting and waiting for almost 2 hours.
I would make a live CD but I don't have any clean DVD's only CD's and Ubuntu cant fit on a standard CD.

Comment: You don't need a CD to make a live CD, just install it on a regular USB-stick

Comment: Is that not what "burning" it on your USB is? I listed the programs i used above.

Comment: You also wrote you were out of DVD/CD for a new live CD. Please clear up your question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in the bootable usb a folder called **syslinux** and not **isolinux** if so, rename it and change :
 the **isolinux.bin** to **syslinux.bin** 
 and **syslinux.cfg** to **isolinux.cfg** // you'll find them in syslinux folder